# select picker bootstrap change noneSelectedText

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select

Is it possible to change the message of a select picker, if nothing is selected. For now, 'Nothing selected' is written. I know, the noneSelectedText attribute contains that message.

But I dont want to change it in the bootstrap.select.js. I want to change it dynamically, because I use different select pickers at different locations.

Edit:

Thank you, it works :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Set `title` attribute to your selects.

```
<select multiple title="Empty" class="selectpicker">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>

<select multiple title="No Value" class="selectpicker">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/56zr619d/)**

Comment: Hi, related to `selectpicker` class for dropdown, the default color is grey, how to change the grey color to clear color?

Comment: @mastersuse Probably should be in a separate question.

Answer (score 17):

with help of - [this](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/210) I tried it works .

1st step - we have to add `data-none-selected-text` attribute in Html select tag.
example -

```
<select name="your_sel_name" multiple class="form-control selectpicker" data-selected-text-format="count" data-none-selected-text >
```

2nd Step - in js on **page load** use `noneSelectedText` option 
example -

```
$(".selectpicker").selectpicker({
        noneSelectedText : 'Please Select' // by this default 'Nothing selected' -->will change to Please Select
    });
```

Hope it will Help some-one Thanks!

Comment: I just added [data-none-selected-text=" "] attribute to the <select> element and didn't need to do anything on the JS side

Comment: And I used just the second step and also worked for me :)

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I just needed to add this HTML code :

```
data-none-selected-text="please select..."
```

when defining `<select>`, so my working code:

```
<select name="..." class="..." data-none-selected-text="please select...">
<option>...</option>                    
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

You ca use content attribute of html to dynamically load the content value `content : "No Value selected"`